# Find the direction of the clock arrow

Tags: geometry, applications

A clock is placed such that at 12 noon its small arrow points towards north-east. In which direction does its large arrow point at 1.30 p.m?
(A) North
(B) South
(C) East
(D) West
(E) None of these

Answer (score 1):

Let N be 0, NE 45, E 90 and so on. Hour hand in each minute moves $0,5\,^{\circ}$. After 90 minutes it will be $45\,^{\circ}$, so As we started at $45\,^{\circ}$, with minute hand (where minute and hour was it this same place) and we add next $45\,^{\circ}$ we have our hour point pointing East.